# Sample from pdf for discrete r.v

Tags: random, mcmc

I have a random variable that can take 4 different values (4,8,16,32)and I would like to update it via sampling from its pdf, which is proportional to:

```
\begin{equation}
    \pi(\nu)\prod_{i=1}^N(\Gamma(\nu/2)(\nu/2)^{(\nu/2)})^{-1} \lambda_i^{(\nu/2 -1)} e^{-\nu\lambda_i/2}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: I believe you're missing an equal sign in there, and I'm sure you're missing a whole lot of explanation about the parameterization. General approach is calculate your function for the four values and sum, normalize each function by evaluation by the sum to make it a valid pdf.  Then generate the CDF from the pdf, generate a U ~ uniform(0,1), and see which CDF values U falls between to determine the outcome.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I would like to know for example whether I could just update the probabilities using this formula and then sample using the updated probabilities?

Comment: I don't see why not.  Your formula requires evaluating two transcendental functions, exp and gamma, but it looks like you can pre-evaluate and store the gammas.  I wouldn't think rebuilding the CDF for four outcomes would be prohibitive.  It would help if you defined your notation though.  I'm operating on the assumption that `nu` represents your four outcomes.